# scikit_posthocs not recognised in github environment.yml

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, yaml

I am trying to create a myBinder launcher for my jupyter note book. Everything works with all dependencies loading apart from scikit_posthocs, which is not recognised.

name: example-environment

channels:

- conda-forge

dependencies:

- numpy
- psutil
- toolz
- matplotlib
- dill
- pandas
- partd
- bokeh
- seaborn
- xlrd
- scikit-learn
- scipy
- statsmodels
- scikit_posthocs

Comment: Add `anaconda` to the channels.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still doesn't recognise the package
ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - scikit-posthocs

Comment: Try with `scikit-posthocs` (dash rather than underscore)

Comment: Thanks. I had tried both already. Neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs since the `scikit-posthocs` library is not compiled in conda and since not available from the conda package manager and is only available in `pip`. Thus you need to add those packages under `pip` in the `.yml` file. Here is a documentation on how to do so. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-file-manually. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
name: example-environment
channels:
 - conda-forge
dependencies:
 - numpy
 - psutil
 - toolz
 - matplotlib
 - dill
 - pandas
 - parts
 - bokeh
 - seaborn
 - xlrd
 - scikit-learn
 - scipy
 - statsmodels
 - pip:
   - scikit-posthocs
```

Comment: Thank you Arjun. You got me most of the way there. I had to remove -scikit_posthocs from the dependencies list and then it worked fine! That was way more difficult than it should have been!

Comment: Haha made a mistake while copying from your requirements above. Good to know you solved it and thanks for the edit (: